# Colouring the sides of a pentagon with three different colours

Tags: combinatorics

[image: Here's the problem]

Let's suppose the colours are: Red, Green, Blue

Since there needs to be  3 colours at the same time, then this could be partitioned into 6 different cases:

- 3G 1B 1R
- 3B 1G 1R
- 3R 1G 1B
- 2B 2G 1R
- 2R 2G 1B
- 2B 2R 1G

Each of the first three cases would yield $\frac{5!}{3!}\ = 5*4 = 20$

Each of the last three cases would yield $\frac{5!}{2!2!}\ = 3$

Thus in total there is $69$ different ways.

Please, point out any flaws in my answer. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Here you must consider circular arrangement of colours on Pentagon. Cases like $GGGBR$ and $GGBRG$ are same. You have overcounted.

In the first three cases, total number of ways will be $\frac{4!}{3!} = 4$

Well as a side note, I must point out that two cases are enough for this problem:

- Three of same kind, One of the other two kinds ($AAABC,BBBAC,CCCAB$)
- Two of a kind, Two of another kind, One of another kind ($AABBC, AACCB, BBCCA$)

Comment: So, in a way it's similar to seating people around a table?

Comment: @SxS Yes. Here the strategy can be that, you first put one color on one side (all sides are identical). Now this converts to linear arrangement, which can be easily dealt with :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that adjacent sides may have the same color, but all three colors have to be used.

There are $3^5$ ways to color the sides arbitrarily, but $3\cdot 2^5$ of these use at most two colors. The difference $3^5-3\cdot 2^5$ does not account for the uniform colorings in the proper way: They should not be counted at all. Now $RRRRR$ is counted once in $3^5$ and then is deducted twice as member of the $RB$-colorings and of the $RG$-colorings. It follows that we have to add $3\cdot1$  to the previous number, so that there are
$$3^5-3\cdot 2^5+3\cdot1=250\tag{1}$$
admissible colorings of the five sides. (In $(1)$ we see an inclusion-exclusion process!)

If we identify colorings differing just by a rotation we obtain ${250\over5}=50$ different types of colorings.

Answer (score 0):

let $S_{1}$ be the set of all
colorings of the vertices of a regular pentagon in which exactly two vertices are red, exactly two are Green and the remaining
is blue so,
$S_{1}=^5 C_{2} \times ^3 C _{1}=30 $

let $S_{2}$ be the set of all
colorings of the vertices of a regular pentagon in which exactly 3 vertices are red, exactly 1 are Green and blue so,
$S_{2}=^5 C_{3} \times ^2 C _{1}=20 $

Adding both, total possible cases$ =30+20= 50$